# How to display Microsoft word document on html page using jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I need to display Microsoft Doc on my web page and then parse the doc for further process.

Comment: Want to display pdf as well as word doc on same web page.

Comment: I am not reading from user local system . Lets take scenario , there is upload option for admin in my application , admin uploads the some doc file ,and all user can able to download and see the file ,file will be stored in my server .Now download happens from same server . I want to give little flexibility to user so that he need not to download file and open in his/her local system instead my application enable viewing doc on browser itself .

Comment: I am able to open pdf and image files in view mode on browser itself with help of jquery plugin . Looking something like this for doc/xls/ppt file type

Answer (score 0):

Use something like: http://poi.apache.org/document/index.html
to parse your word document and extract the data. Then render it as HTML to client browser.

But it sound poor to do that. Better would be to use a format which can directly displayed in the browser like PDF. Then you don't have to parse between the word doc styles and your webpage styles.

Comment: Thanks, will do we have any specific HTML-code by which we can display directly  on web page any suggestions?

Comment: No, word in the old OLE style format is microsoft specific. The xml based docx docs are open document standard, possible for this you will find libraries that directly parse a docx to html.

Comment: No because I dont have one and I don't know a library. That is task you can handle your self by using google.

Comment: I did it and found directly about 5 different aproaches and libraries to do this. Most of them are closed source and you have to licence the library for your purpose. Here a java library http://www.aspose.com/java/word-component.aspx

Comment: I am not reading from user local system . Lets take scenario , there is upload option for admin in my application , admin uploads the some doc file ,and all user can able to download and see the file ,file will be stored in my server .Now download happens from same server . I want to give little flexibility to user so that he need not to download file and open in his/her local system instead my application enable viewing doc on browser itself .

Comment: I am able to open pdf and image files in view mode on browser itself with help of jquery plugin . Looking something like this for doc/xls/ppt file type

Comment: Sorry that is out of scope of SF ;) You can contact me directly and my Company will offer you consulting ;) Or use google, which is sheeper ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org/) to parse the doc file.

Comment: Want to display pdf as well as word doc on same web page.

Comment: for PDF you can use iText

Comment: For Word Document you can use POI from apache i have given link and for PDF viewer you can use iText you have to use in a same page if you want to show both the things on a same jsp